# How can someone modify React states from the browser without using react dev tools?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a site and recently someone managed to "hack" and change some values ​​of the react states that allowed him to see things that they should not have seen (for example an admin panel)

And other things like changing its userId (since it was saved in a useState) so every time I did an operation on my database I could see a userId = "1" which was impossible for me to happen

The first thing I thought is that the user use react dev tools to see the states and change them from there, but when I tried to use react dev tools on my own I saw that the states could not be modified like if it was on localhost

So how could this user have done to modify my react states?

My site is made with NextJS 14.0.0 in case this information is useful

Comment: Did the user tell you that they did this by modifying state?  If so, did you ask them what specifically they did?  Or are you assuming they were modifying state, when they may have done something else entirely?  Even without React dev tools, while it may be more difficult in many cases, in the end what they have is JavaScript code running in their browser.  And they can modify that JavaScript code any way they like.  Without knowing more about what actually happened, I don't see how we can be more specific.

Comment: @David I didn't ask him what he did, it's an assumption but it seems very similar to me as if someone managed to modify the states of react...

He could also have modified the javascript code, but what is certain is that he managed to alter either the states or the code, how can someone do that? Do they inject code into the browser? Or does it have a different extension that allows someone to modify things?

Comment: don't rule out the possibility that you have a bug in your code that caused userId to incorrectly get set to 1.

Comment: @iandev: It's their own browser, they can modify whatever they like.  They can open their dev tools, place breakpoints in the code, execute code on their console, etc., etc.  Do you know that they even did that?  How have you confirmed they haven't just exploited a bug in your code?  Or not even used your code at all and crafted their own HTTP request to your server?  What *did* the user claim to have done?  What actual effect did you observe?  Was it something you saw them do in their browser, or some effect you saw in the data on the server?

Comment: Thanks @David for your answer, the questions you asked me made me think a lot and my current conclusion is that the user probably simply modified payloads of some POST requests and modified the JS of my site, evading a couple of validations...

I really appreciate your comments here, Greg's answer was very helpful to me and I accepted it.

Right now I'm adding server side validations, but thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first rule of UI development: *you cannot trust the client*.

You do not control the computer that the client is running on, so anyone with minor skills can take control over the environment and your client app code is no longer "in charge".

For web apps, it is a fairly simple matter to go to the JS Console and begin interacting with whatever JS code is running on a given page (or "web app").  React is not magic.  It is a library that manages JS information in a common format...and because of that anyone that understands how to debug or interact with JS via the console can easily manipulate the state of the app.

There is no security on the UI layer of a web app.  The only way to enforce security is to do it on your backend (i.e. on the "server").

This is true of any and all apps that run on someone else's computer.